# Ошибка ORA-00947 "not enough values" при returning BULK COLLECT INTO во вложеную тблицу

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, update

Получаю ошибку при попытке получить массив значений из открытого курсора при обновлении данных во вложенную таблицу с пользовательским типом данных.

Так создаю вложенную таблицу с пользовательским типом на уровне БД:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "FOO_STATUS" AS OBJECT (
    a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER)
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FOO_STATUS_TABLE IS TABLE OF FOO_STATUS
/
```

Так выглядит процедура в пакете:

```
PROCEDURE foo (...) IS
    l_foo FOO_STATUS_TABLE := FOO_STATUS_TABLE();
BEGIN
    UPDATE foo_table SET ...
    WHERE ...
    RETURNING foo_table_a, foo_table_b, c BULK COLLECT INTO l_foo;
END;
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

Где не хватает значений, и как исправить ошибку?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [ORA-00947 "not enough values" when UPDATE returning BULK COLLECT INTO user created TYPE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63041830) от участника [@Rodrigo Gurgel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1154581/rodrigo-gurgel)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Так как  `l_foo` это вложенная таблица с колонкой объектного типа, то необходимо собирать в неё сущности этого объектного типа, а не отдельные значения:

```
returning foo_status (a, b, c) bulk collect into l_foo
```

Кроме того, так будут возвращены новые значения колонок. Но часто интересно сохранить значения колонок до их изменения (старые).

Следуюший воспроизводимый пример сохранит оба значения:

```
var rc refcursor 
declare
    old footab;
    new footab;
begin
    update foo f1 set 
        a = a*10, b = b*10, c = c*10
    where 1=1
    returning (
        select foorow (a,b,c) 
        from dual), foorow (a,b,c) bulk collect into old, new;
        
    open :rc for 
        select 'old:' vals, o.* from table (old) o union all 
        select 'new:' vals, n.* from table (new) n;
end;
/

VALS          A          B          C
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
old:          1          2          3
old:          4          5          6
old:          7          8          9
new:         10         20         30
new:         40         50         60
new:         70         80         90
```

---

**На заметку**

Если `UPDATE` содержит клаузу `log errors reject limit`, а при изменении возникнет ошибка, то `returning` вернёт значения **только для обновлённых записей**. Новые значения для записей, на которых произошла ошибка, можно узнать в логе ошибок, например, в таблице `err$_foo` для примера выше.

---

Подготовка схемы для примера:

```
create or replace type foorow as object (a int, b int, c int);
/
create or replace type footab as table of foorow;
/
create table foo (a int, b int, c int)
/
insert all 
    into foo values (1,2,3)
    into foo values (4,5,6)
    into foo values (7,8,9)
select 1 from dual;
commit;
```