# Как в запросе на изменение вернуть значение колонки до этого изменения?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, update

Допустим, есть запись в таблице `myTable`:

```
id  letter 
 1  a
```

Можно просто сделать следующее:

```
update myTable set
    letter = 'b'
where id = 1
returning letter into myVariable;
```

и `myVariable` получт значение `b`.

Ищю как в `returning` получить значение колонки `letter` "перед тем, как". Чтобы предыдущий запрос на изнменение, например, выглядел бы как-то так:

```
update myTable set
    letter = 'b'
where id = 1
returning letter "до изменения" into myVariable;
```

То есть, `myVariable` должна получить значение `a`.

В T-SQL можно достичь этого с помощью `OUTPUT`. Есть ли аналогичный способ в *Oracle*, чтобы не делать отдельный запрос только для того, чтобы получить предыдущее значение колонки?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle SQL - can I return the "before" state of a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40522950) от участника [@Pancho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3051627/pancho)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/40522950

Answer (score 3):

```
update (
    select T.*, (select letter from DUAL) old_letter
    from myTable T
    where id=1
  ) set letter = 'b'
returning old_letter into myVariable;
```

Работоспособность проверена на Oracle 11.2 (*прим.ред.: проверено до 19.3  вкл.*).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523568) от участника [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5669174/mike)</sub>

Comment: А без подзапроса, тупо `update(select t.*, letter as old_letter ...` - не работает? Или, для уничтожения связи, `update(select t.*,concat(letter,'') as old_letter ...`.

Comment: @Akina Не, не работает. Или так, или подзапрос в самом returning, как давал парой ответов раньше (последнее мне нравится больше, но это дело вкуса).

Comment: Подзапрос в RETURNING вообще без вопросов лучше - хотя бы с точки зрения количества обрабатываемых подзапросом записей. Кстати, а если представить, что таких записей несколько? А если ещё представить, что некоторые записи из них не обновляются (скажем, из-за какого-то ограничения и ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING, или как оно там выглядит у Оракла)?

Comment: @Akina Если записей несколько, то bulk collect как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1163086/217579). Если с логгированием ошибок, то вроде не пишет в returning (не уверен, надо потестить, как сделаю напишу).

Comment: @Akina Да, returning срабатывает только на записи без ошибки. Добавил замечание в [той теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1163086/217579).